# How to change current route in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, url, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Here is my route; http://localhost:3000/homes/California/buy/, and I'm trying to use vue-router to change the route to http://localhost:3000/homes/California/rent/. I have tried doing this;

```html
<router-link
        :to="{ path: `homes/${this.$route.params.search}/rent/` }"
        tag="p"
      >
        Rent
</router-link>
```

But it appends the path to the previous path. So I get http://localhost:3000/homes/California/buy/homes/California/rent/.

I even thought it's maybe the `this.$route.params.search`, so I replaced the path to; `homes/Chicago/buy/`, it still didn't work. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path you've supplied to the `<router-link>` is a relative path. You need to prefix the path with a `/` so that it is relative to the root of the website, rather than the current page:

```html
<router-link
        :to="{ path: `/homes/${this.$route.params.search}/rent/` }"
        tag="p"
      >
        Rent
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a `/` before `homes` to make it an absolute path. please try with the below code.

```
<router-link
    :to="{ path: `/homes/${this.$route.params.search}/rent/` }"
    tag="p"
  >
    Rent
</router-link>
```